# How to add appodeal ads to the project?

Tags: appodeal

I want to add appodeal ads SDK to my project. When I try to sign in, a statement appears with the issue of "Your account is on moderation".
Could you please help me that what is wrong and how to fix it?
Regurds

Comment: I am also facing the same issue - "Your account is on moderation"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.